# SQL Server Reports IDE for creating reports

Tags: sql, report

I have to modify SQL Server reports. It is not easy to modify directly XML report file (*.rdl). Is there any IDE for editing SQL Server Reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official recommendation is to install the `Business Intelligence Development Studio`, which is part of the SQL Server product - this will install into your existing Visual Studio, if you have one, or it will install a Visual Studio shell for your use.

As far as I remember, there's a least one other report designer out there that allows you to visually design your RDL/RDLC files - but I can't seem to find my references to that one anymore.. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

MS Visual Studio with Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers.

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 Products

1. Business Intelligence Development Studio, this is Visual Studio you need to start the SQL Server Setup.exe from your SQL Server Version on your client PC. But install only the Client-Software (with all Options) then it installs the SQL Server Management Studio, Visual Studio and some more Tools you need.
2. Go on the Report Server URL similar like http:///reports then click on the button  or click on the menubutton of a report an then . At first time it installs the Report Builder (~80MB) on your client.
   Otherwise you can install the Report Builder seperat: [Report Builder Download](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=6116)
   But with Report Builder you don't have Code-Highlight or other coding features. And the SQL Creator is not the same as in Visual Studio or in Management Studio.